# Flutter firestore: Query Document with 'where' & DISTINCT Document Field

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to query my database so that it returns Distinct Value of the chosen field. (Like SELECT DICTINCT) in MySQL.

Example: I queried my firstore Collection to get Documents where field `messageTo` isEqualTo 'Terry', this works fine but returns multiple documents with the same field 'chatID'.

I'd like to query the Collection to return Documents where field `messageTo` isEqualTo 'Terry' and making 'ChatID' field as DISTINCT value.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore doesn't have anything that's equivalent to "select distinct".  You will have to make a decision on the client by looking at the returned documents from a query.

It's worth noting, in a more general sense, that Firestore also does not offer any sort of projection view of documents when using client app APIs.  Distinct selection is effectively a projection, because it only returns certain fields.  Firestore document fetches and queries always return all the fields in a document.